# Ruby on Rails select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using select_tag for a listbox,for creating a user,user is getting creating but in database null value is getting stored for the selected option from the listbox.

View code:

```
    About     :
<div class="field">
  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp
  <%= select_tag "about_id",options_from_collection_for_select(@abouts, "id", "name"),:multiple =>true%>
</div>
```

Controller action create:

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
      Query.query_confirmation(@student).deliver

       format.html { redirect_to :controller=>"students",:action=>"new", notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        flash[:notice]="Your Question has been sent to the University they will revert back soon"
        format.json { render json: @student, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: The log file is your friend. Check that to see what you are actually receiving in your params for a student in the create method, and how those attributes relate to your definition of a student in the database.

Comment: Started GET "/students/new?notice=Student+was+successfully+created." for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-03 10:11:31 +0530
Processing by StudentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"notice"=>"Student was successfully created."}
  [1m[36mAbout Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `abouts`.* FROM `abouts` [0m

  Rendered students/_form.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered students/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 18.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
this is what i am getting in log file

Comment: That's the log excerpt from 1 step after the step you should be looking at.  What you need to be looking at is the log related to creating the student (the step that processes the submit).  That's where the params populated by your form are reconstituted into a student and stored in the database.  Do your params match your data structure?  I don't believe your 'student' is designed to handle a multi-select input for about_id.

Comment: in logger it is fetching the multiple values but inserting null as a value in database.